# Como configurar proxy en una aplicacion de C#

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

Necesito conectar una aplicacion que estoy desarrollando en C# a Internet a traves de un proxy. Para ello estoy utilizando la clase 'System.Net.WebProxy' de .NET de la siguiente manera:

```
var webProxy = new WebProxy("proxy.uh.cu/estudiantes.pac", 80);
webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myEmail@estudiantes.matcom.uh.cu", "myPassword");
```

y aun asi, la aplicacion no se conecta. Estoy haciendo algo mal aqui?

Comment: No se conecta quiere decir que tira algun error? como te estas conectado despues de hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Te está dando algún mensaje de error? Adicional, el puerto se incluye en la dirección, y luego se especifica si se ignora el proxy en direcciones locales. Prueba así: var webProxy = new WebProxy("proxy.uh.cu/estudiantes.pac:80", true); WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;

Comment: no deberias hacer nada en tu codigo, se supone que el proxy que permite la salida a internet lo configuras en windows. Ademas como es que la applicacion se conecta, digo usas la clase WebClient o HttpClient?